# comparar entre listas en C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Hola me podrían ayudar a hacer el siguiente filtro soy nuevo programando
Tengo 2 listas de  entidades

```
    List<ExtraccionMasiva> lst_ExtraccionMasiva;      
    List<Extraccion> lstExel = new List<Extraccion>();
```

Como validar que los registros de `lstExel` existan o no en `lst_ExtraccionMasiva`

Y llenar dos listas nuevas, una con los que si están registrados en `LSt_ExtraccionMasiva` y otra con los que no tienen registro.

Esto es en C#

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te invito a mirar [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Por favor siempre coloca tu código y lo que hayas intentado. En este caso, podrías dar un ejemplo mínimo verificable para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias ayudarte con `linq` para realizar un `left join` y validar que items esta en una lista pero no en la otr

```
var query = from l1 in lst_ExtraccionMasiva
             join l2 in lstExel on l1.Prop1 equals l2.Prop2 into gj
            from l3 in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where l3 == null
            select l1;
```

De esta forma obtienes los items de la primera lista que no estan en la segunda

[Realizar operaciones de combinación externa izquierda](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins)

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné de la siguiente manera:

```cs
 var ConRegistro = from expedientes1 in lista1
                   join exppedientes2 in lista2 on expedientes.valor1 equals 
                   expedientes2.valor2
                   select expedientes1;

 var sinRegistro = expedientes1.Except(ConRegistro).ToList();
```